# Unable to connect to WiFi after the upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, drivers, upgrade

I was previously running Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS and have just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and after the upgrade my WiFi driver is no longer working. I know that is vague, so for further insight what I mean is before the upgrade I could boot Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS and automatically connect to my wireless network, since upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS all I have is red X over the two computers). What do I need to do to get the WiFi working on my Ubuntu install.

My computer is below and from Windows device manager my Wireless Card info is:

> Toshiba Satellite P755-S5320
>   Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1000

Answer (score 0):

My desktop went to same problem after upgrading to 14.04 lts from 12.04 lts.

I found that the drivers needed were commented out in `/etc/modprobe/blacklist.conf`. I uncommented it and then booted desktop.

My wifi is Ralink 5370, using RT2800 drivers.